# Complex subset of a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with close to a million objects in it. I need an efficient to way to subset the data based on multiple criteria. I can do this is a for loop but was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this.

```
Time    Instance    Server  Metric  Value
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID1 Server888   disk.commandsaveraged.average   0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID1 Server999   disk.commandsaveraged.average   0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID1 Server777   disk.commandsaveraged.average   0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID1 Server888   disk.commandsaveraged.average   0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID1 Server999   disk.commandsaveraged.average   0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID1 Server777   disk.commandsaveraged.average   0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID2 Server888   disk.commandsaveraged.average   0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID2 Server888   disk.commandsaveraged.average   0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID3 Server999   disk.commandsaveraged.average   0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID3 Server999   disk.commandsaveraged.average   0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID3 Server777   disk.commandsaveraged.average   0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID3 Server777   disk.commandsaveraged.average   0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID1 Server888   disk.numberreadaveraged.average 0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID1 Server999   disk.numberreadaveraged.average 0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID1 Server777   disk.numberreadaveraged.average 0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID1 Server888   disk.numberreadaveraged.average 0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID1 Server999   disk.numberreadaveraged.average 0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID1 Server777   disk.numberreadaveraged.average 0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID2 Server888   disk.numberreadaveraged.average 0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID2 Server888   disk.numberreadaveraged.average 0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID3 Server999   disk.numberreadaveraged.average 0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID3 Server999   disk.numberreadaveraged.average 0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID3 Server777   disk.numberreadaveraged.average 0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID3 Server777   disk.numberreadaveraged.average 0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID1 Server888   disk.numberwriteaveraged.average    0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID7 Server999   disk.numberwriteaveraged.average    0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID1 Server777   disk.numberwriteaveraged.average    0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID1 Server888   disk.numberwriteaveraged.average    0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID1 Server999   disk.numberwriteaveraged.average    0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID7 Server777   disk.numberwriteaveraged.average    0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID2 Server888   disk.numberwriteaveraged.average    0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID5 Server888   disk.numberwriteaveraged.average    0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID3 Server999   disk.numberwriteaveraged.average    0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID4 Server999   disk.numberwriteaveraged.average    0
17/08/2014 04:00:00 PM  ID3 Server777   disk.numberwriteaveraged.average    0
17/08/2014 04:05:00 PM  ID3 Server777   disk.numberwriteaveraged.average    0
```

What I want to do is create a subset where `metric == disk.numberwriteaveraged.average` , `Server == Server999 & Server == Server888` AND WHERE both servers have the same instance ID's in common.

NOTE, I use the term subset purely because I don't know of any other way to filter data i R, still learning. I am looking for speed and I will be generating data sets much larger than my current one.

Comment: So, are there one or two cases in this data that meet the set of conditions? (At the moment the specification is not making sense to me but if there were one or two line you could point to then maybe it would help make it more concrete.) I cann figure out at the moment how this can be simultaneously true: `Server == 'Server999' & Server == 'Server888'`

Comment: http://datascience.stackexchange.com may be of interest to you

Comment: @BondedDust, I think he mean something like `Metric == "disk.commandsaveraged.average" &  (Server == "Server999" | Server == "Server888")`

Comment: It's not really an R problem. More of a thought problem.

Comment: There are currently 226 unique instance ID's that are distributed throughout the data , each server will have a varying number of instance ID's associated to it. I am looking for where two server share the instance ID's. So this could be two servers sharing one instance or two servers sharing 10. hopefully that explained it a little better.

Comment: So server777 and server999 both have an instance ID in common? (Actually more than one in common.)

Answer (score 2):

(If I understand your question correctly) In your case, `data.table` is your friend. Try (assuming `df` is your data set):

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- setDT(df)[, .SD[Metric == "disk.commandsaveraged.average" & 
            (Server == "Server999" | Server == "Server888")], by = Instance]
```

Comment: Just ran a test with the above code and it looks to be spot on. thanks!!

Comment: Ok, so after doing a test with my full data set I am still getting a full list of all the instances across both servers. effectively I am looking for the intersecting instances.

Comment: what I have ended up doing which looks to work fine is the following

ServerData <- setDT(Mydata)[, .SD[Metric == "disk.commandsaveraged.average" & Server == "SRV2"], keyby = Instance]
GUestData <- setDT(Mydata)[, .SD[Metric == "disk.commandsaveraged.average" & Server == "SRV1"], keyby = Instance]

dataset <- rbind(ServerData[ServerData$Instance %in% GUestData$Instance],GUestData)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Next time try to create a good reproducible example with how the desired output should look like, otherwise it is impossible to understand what you need.